# Metasploitable 2: Unable to fetch some archives

Tags: apt, metasploit

I just installed Metasploitable 2 from [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metasploitable/) on VMware Workstation Pro. After logging in, I tried `sudo apt-get install whois` and I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  whois
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 139 not upgraded.
Need to get 31.9kB of archives.
After this operation, 279kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages could not be authenticated:
  whois
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com hardy/main whois 4.7.24
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/whois/whois_4.7.24_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

This happens with anything, not just whois.

I tried `sudo apt-get update` (with and without `-fix--missing`), and it ends up with a lot of "Failed to fetch" and ends with an error ("Some index files failed to download...").
If I try `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the same result as installing.

I also tried `-o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false`.

The `date` command returned the time in EDT, 7 hours behind my clock, which is correct.

I am also connected to the internet since I am able to ping `8.8.8.8`.

Please can you help me fix it?

Comment: The error message makes sense since Ubuntu 8.04 LTS (Hardy Heron) support ended on 12 May 2011 for desktops and 9 May 2013 for servers. The debs are now in old-releases.ubuntu.com. Are you using Ubuntu 8.04?

Comment: @Kulfy Ah, makes sense. I haven't thought about it. I checked the version using `lsb_release -a`, and Metasploitable 2 is indeed using Ubuntu 8.04. Is there still a way to install?

Comment: @Kulfy Thank you so much! The accepted answer there worked for me.

Comment: You can close your question as duplicate by choosing "Yes" and click on "Submit" button which must appear at the top of your question.